# composer Requirements could not be resolved to an unstable set of packages

Tags: php, yii, yii2, composer-php

i want to install yii from composer and then i see this error[image: error]

and i change my  "minimum-stability": to dev but still i see this error

my composer is:

```
{
"name": "yiisoft/yii2-app-basic",
"description": "Yii 2 Basic Project Template",
"keywords": ["yii2", "framework", "basic", "project template"],
"homepage": "http://www.yiiframework.com/",
"type": "project",
"license": "BSD-3-Clause",
"support": {
    "issues": "https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/issues?state=open",
    "forum": "http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/",
    "wiki": "http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/",
    "irc": "irc://irc.freenode.net/yii",
    "source": "https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2"
},
"minimum-stability": "dev",

"require": {
    "php": ">=5.4.0",
    "yiisoft/yii2": "~2.0.5",
    "yiisoft/yii2-bootstrap": "~2.0.0",
    "yiisoft/yii2-swiftmailer": "~2.0.0"
},
"require-dev": {
    "yiisoft/yii2-debug": "~2.0.0",
    "yiisoft/yii2-gii": "~2.0.0",
    "yiisoft/yii2-faker": "~2.0.0",

    "codeception/base": "^2.2.3",
    "codeception/verify": "~0.3.1",
    "codeception/specify": "~0.4.3"
},
"config": {
    "process-timeout": 1800
},
"scripts": {
    "post-create-project-cmd": [
        "yii\\composer\\Installer::postCreateProject"
    ]
},
"extra": {
    "yii\\composer\\Installer::postCreateProject": {
        "setPermission": [
            {
                "runtime": "0777",
                "web/assets": "0777",
                "yii": "0755"
            }
        ],
        "generateCookieValidationKey": [
            "config/web.php"
        ]
    },
    "asset-installer-paths": {
        "npm-asset-library": "vendor/npm",
        "bower-asset-library": "vendor/bower"
    }
}
```

}
i dont know why this error on composer update appear?

Comment: my composer version is 1.4.1

Comment: Have you got [fxp plugin asset installed](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-start-installation.html#installing-from-composer) or are you one of those people that don't read instructions?

Comment: Your error image doesn't open for me.Please type it.

Comment: Have you tried to install this package that composer requires? `bower-asset/jquery` ?